# How much money would you make if you acquired $1\%$ of all iPhone sales?

Tags: percentages, word-problem

Me and a friend had a dispute over the answer to this question today. The scenario is:

> If you got $1\%$ of iPhone sales (Assuming $\$900$ in Canadian Dollars), how much would you make over Ten Million ($10{,}000{,}000$) sales?

We have two answers, and each believe we are correct.

I believe the following:

$1\%$ of $900$ is $9$. $9$ times $10{,}000{,}000$ equals $90{,}000{,}000$. So you would make $\$90{,}000{,}000$ over Ten Million Sales. Alternatively, you could do $900\times 10{,}000{,}000 = 9{,}000{,}000{,}000$ (Nine Billion) and $1\%$ of $9{,}000{,}000{,}000$ is Ninety Million Dollars.

My friend believes that the answer would be $81{,}000{,}000$ using the standard steps to calculate percentage. Although I believe he got the math wrong, (Multiplying by $0.09$ instead of $0.01$) he insists he is correct.

Who is correct between us?

Comment: Clearly you are correct. Your friend used the wrong percentage.

Comment: Not only that, but your friend did the wrong way wrong (unless it was a typo).  Using 0.09 instead of 0.01 will yield 810,000,000 and not 81,000,000.

Comment: *"[...] using the standard steps to calculate percentage."* Can you show these "standard steps" he did? Did he just take $9\%$ of the revenue? If so, have him explain how $9\% = 1\%$.

Answer (score 15):

$$Percent \times price \times units = 1\% \times $900 \times 10,000,000 = $90,000,000$$

Answer (score 5):

---

Cost per iPhone: $900

Quantity sold: 10,000,000

Retained earnings: 1% = 0.01

> $$c := \$900$$
>   $$\space\space\space q := 10,000,000$$
>   $$\space\space\space p := 0.01$$

$$c \cdot q \cdot p = \$900 \times 10,000,00 \times 0.01 = \$90,000,000$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply find the $1\%$ of $\$900$ i.e.,

$$\dfrac{x}{900}=\dfrac{1}{100}$$
$$x=\dfrac{900}{100}$$
$$x=9$$

And simply multiply by Ten Million $(10,000,000)$
$$9\times10,000,000=\$90,000,000$$
I hope it' ll help.